# Haskell using IO on a function that doesn't expect it

Tags: haskell, sdl, io-monad

**Question:**

How do I give an "IO SDL.Surface" to a function that expects an "SDL.Surface"?

I'd rather rethink my entire approach than resort to using something like "unsafePerformIO", unless this is actually the correct time to use it (which I doubt).

**Further info:**

I had a file filled with numbers and filepaths and I've parsed this file and loaded the images located at these paths into a list [(Int, IO SDL.Surface)]. Problem is, that the [SDL.blitSurface](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL-0.5.9/docs/Graphics-UI-SDL-Video.html) function expects a normal SDL.Surface.

Error message:

```
Couldn't match type `IO SDL.Surface'
              with `GHC.ForeignPtr.ForeignPtr SDL.SurfaceStruct'
Expected type: SDL.Surface
Actual type: IO SDL.Surface
```

I'm not sure that source code is necessary to answer the question, but I'll provide some anyway just in case it helps:

To load an image file I use:

```
loadImage :: FilePath -> IO SDL.Surface
loadImage [] = error "empty list"
loadImage a =
  SDL.loadBMP a
```

To create the list of numbers and images I use:

```
createIDImageList :: [Tiletype] -> [(Int, IO SDL.Surface)]
createIDImageList a =
  if null a then []
  else [(tiletypeid $ a !! 0, loadImage (C8.unpack ( tiletypeimage ( a !! 0))))] ++ createIDImageList (tail a)
```

To retrieve the correct picture from this list, I use this function:

```
imageFromID :: Int -> [(Int, IO SDL.Surface)] -> Maybe (IO SDL.Surface)
imageFromID a b =
  if null b then Nothing
  else if a == (fst $ b !! 0) then Just (snd $ b !! 0)
  else imageFromID a (tail b)
```

And finally I use the imageFromID with the SDL.blitSurface to draw the image, except that I can't due to IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you end up with `[IO Foobar]`, what you *probably* want is actually `IO [Foobar]`. The `sequence` function transforms one into the other. Or you can use `mapM` instead of `map` when creating the list in the first place.

In your example, it's a little more complicated, since we have `[(Int, IO Surface)]`. Let me see what I can suggest...

`loadImage` is an I/O action. It takes a filename and returns an IO action to load the image. Your `createIDImageList` function is really

```
createIDImageList = map f
  where
    f a = (tiletypeid a, loadImage (C8.unpack ( tiletypeimage a) ) )
```

What you probably want to do is change `f` to have type `IO (Int, Surface)` rather than `(Int, IO Surface)`. And then you can `mapM f`, yielding a single I/O action that returns a list of stuff.

```
createIDImageList :: [Tiletype] -> IO [(Int, SDL.Surface)]
createIDImageList = mapM f
  where
    f a = do
      surface <- loadImage (C8.unpack (tiletypeimage a) )
      return (tiletypeid a, surface)
```

---

Regarding `imageFromID`: what you *probably* want to do is something like this:

```
main = do
  images <- createIDImageList (...)
  ...
  let image5 = imageFromID 5 images
  SDL.blitSurface image5 ...
```

The type of `imageFromID` then becomes

```
imageFromID :: `Int -> [(Int, SDL.Surface)] -> Maybe SDL.Surface
```

(Since `images` now has type `[(Int, SDL.Surface)]`, with no `IO` in it, thanks to `<-`.)

What you're doing here is that `createIDImageList` is actually loading everything off disk, and then you can use `imageFromID` (which has no I/O in it) whenever you want to get the surface you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks MathematicalOrchid, this seems to be indeed in the correct direction. I need to change the imageFromID function as well, don't I?

Comment: @user3638162 Yep, that's right. Can you work it out, or do you need a hint?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a hint. I know the function needs to do become `imageFromID :: Int -> IO [(Int, SDL.Surface)] -> Maybe (SDL.Surface)` but I'm not sure how to write this. I need to use map for this?

Comment: There is a possible future benefit of having an intermediate value with type `[(Int, IO SDL.Surface)]`: you can do things like filter the list before passing it to `sequence`.

Answer (score 0):

```
do image <- loadImage "imagefile"
   blitSurface image rect1 dest rect2
```